# GCP SQL inserts are extremely slow

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I have a basic Postgres instance in GCP with the following configuration:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FFZ6.png

I have a simple python script using pycopg2 that does inserts in a loop to the database connected through the sql auth proxy.

All the inserts are done in the same transaction.

The problem is that it is taking a couple of hours to insert around 200,000 records.

When I run the script on a local database it takes a couple of seconds.

What could be causing this huge difference?

Comment: That is 27.8 ms per statement.  That is a pretty reasonable ping time between on-prem and cloud.  Switch to a method that doesn't send every row in a separate packet, like COPY or multi-row INSERT.

Comment: where are you running the pycopg2 programme ? what is the network rtt between the pycopg2 program and the PGSQL server ?
if you are insering from an other instance, try to use the pipeline mode: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pipeline-mode.html

Comment: Most likely you are interfacing with BigQuery incorrectly (batch versus single row inserts). You do not show the code, so we can only guess.